# getting urls from page html android

Tags: android, html, regex

I wanted to extract two urls inside this page html :

http: //paste.ubuntu.com/7017703/

Main page :

http:// www.clip2ni.com/05/Video-Section/Iranian/download-funny-hassan-rhubarb-concert-at-milad-tower

(it seems too long to post it here because it has thousands of lines of code).

Two urls that I wanted :

> http:// dl.clip2ni.com/m/VIDEO/92-11/3GP/consert25tir-milad.3gp
>
> http:// dl.clip2ni.com/m/VIDEO/92-11/MP4/consert25tir-milad.mp4

is it possible RegEx ? how ? 
is it possible Jsoup ? how ?

[The best Hidden camera](http://www.newclip2ni.com/download-clip/hidden-camera)

Comment: if I wanted to exctract other urls, how can I do by RegEx ? for example: http://one**********.mp4,http://two*******.3gp etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your urls doesn't have any space inside:

```
String input = "http://dl.clip2ni.com/m/VIDEO/92-11/3GP/consert25tir-milad.3gp asdas http://dl.clip2ni.com/m/VIDEO/92-11/MP4/consert25tir-milad.mp4";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(https?://\\s*\\S+\\.(?:3gp|mp4))");    Matcher m = pattern.matcher(input);
while(m.find()) {
  System.out.println(m.group(1));
}
```

Comment: tnx, but the problem is here, I have not any output ! http://paste.ubuntu.com/7017823/ | i added Internet Permission to manifest.xml

Comment: You have space after `http://` means `http:// w` so it doesn't work. If you think there will be an space after `http://` then add a `\\s*` just after the `://` in the regex.

Comment: Tnx, Your Code is Correct. now, how can I get Complete content of my url ? :-?

Comment: You can use URLConnection or HTTPClient to fetch content from url. Check which suits better with you: http://www.innovation.ch/java/HTTPClient/urlcon_vs_httpclient.html